# MySQL list records where coherent growths go wrong

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table with two columns, row1 and row2, and theese columns together increased.

```
+------+------+
| row1 | row2 |
+------+------+
|   10 |  100 |
|   11 |  110 |
|   20 |  200 |
|   21 |  210 |
+------+------+
```

But sometimes an error occured, wrong values inserted:

```
+------+------+
| row1 | row2 |
+------+------+
|   10 |  100 |
|   11 |  110 |
|   20 |  105 |
|   21 |  210 |
+------+------+
```

The row1 = 20, row2 = 105 is "wrong", because the previous row1 is 11, and the corresponding row2 is 110, which is larger than 105.

How can I list theese "wrong" rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use the `LAG()` window function to detect breaks in the `row2` sequence as ordered by `row1`:

```sql
SELECT row1, row2,
       CASE WHEN LAG(row2) OVER (ORDER BY row1) > row2 THEN 'ERROR' ELSE END AS flag
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY row1;
```

The computed `flag` column generated by the above query would contain `ERROR` for any record which is breaking sequence.